# Windows 10, Skype for business

Tags: windows-10, desktop-computer, skype-for-business

Have tried reinstalling skype for business, have done a clean install of windows. Still coming with same error, user can sign in other PC. Tried a working account, same error. Skype account has no issues as it works in other PC. Help.
Error is username, password or domain is incorrect. Contact your administrator.

Answer (score -1):

If I clean install has been tried this isn't likely to be the error but check for a time / date sync issue. I've had that cause similar sounding symptoms.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/skypeforbusiness/troubleshoot/online-sign-in/sfb-online-sign-in-error